# Python - Writing a program that repeatedly prompts user for input, returns the sorted values in a list using linear insertion from back of list

Tags: python, sorting, input

I want to practice the different types of questions I can get for sorting algorithms in my upcoming Python course test.

This particular question says that I should write a program which asks users for inputs until the input is 5555. Each time a number is input by the user, the program should insert the number into its correct position in the list using linear insertion from the back of the list.

Then the program prints the number of items from the list that needed to be compared with the new value to find the correct position and the list with the newly inserted number.

When the user enters the value 5555, the program should stop asking for input, print the sorted list and the total number of comparisons performed.
5555 itself is not inserted into the list.

Restrictions are that I cannot use `break` , `continue`, `sorted()`, `.sort()`, `.index()`, `.find()`, or `.insert()` but I am allowed to use `.append()`

My code:

```
num = 5555
count = 0
new_list = []
user_input = 0
while user_input != num:
    user_input = int(input("Enter input: "))
    
    if user_input != num:
        new_list.append(user_input)
        print ("Comparisons made:", count)
        count += 1
        print (new_list)
    
    if user_input == num:
        print ("Total comparisons:", count)
        count += 1
        print (new_list)
```

This is how the code should work:

```
>>> Enter input: 1   #user_input = 1
    Comparisons made: 0
    [1]
    Enter input: 3   #user_input = 3
    Comparisons made: 1
    [1, 3]
    Enter input: 4   #user_input = 4
    Comparisons made: 1
    [1, 3, 4]
    Enter input: 2   #user_input = 2
    Comparisons made: 3
    [1, 2, 3, 4]
    Enter input: 5555   #user_input = 5555
    Total comparisons made: 5
    [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

My output -

```
Enter input: 1
Comparisons made: 0
[1]
Enter input: 3
Comparisons made: 1
[1, 3]
Enter input: 4
Comparisons made: 2
[1, 3, 4]
Enter input: 2
Comparisons made: 3
[1, 3, 4, 2]
Enter input: 99999
Total comparisons: 4
[1, 3, 4, 2]
```

What I am unable to do is integrate the sorting bit into this question. Could someone help please.

Comment: Can you create a function if you can't use `break` unless you can't use `return`?

Comment: The test cases are specified and they don't call the function so it doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use slicing to insert the `user_input` to the right position. Iterate over your `new_list` and remember the last position (+1) where the `user_input` is greater than or equals to the current element. After that split your list in two parts.

```
num = 5555
count = 0
new_list = []
user_input = 0
while user_input != num:
    user_input = int(input("Enter input: "))
    
    if user_input != num:
        #new_list.append(user_input)
        pos = 0
        for i in range(len(new_list)):
            if user_input >= new_list[i]:
                pos = i + 1
        new_list = new_list[:pos] + [user_input] + new_list[pos:]
        cnt = len(new_list) - 1
        print ("Comparisons made:", cnt)
        count += cnt
        print (new_list)
    
    if user_input == num:
        print ("Total comparisons:", count)
        count += 1
        print (new_list)
```

Output:

```
Enter input: 1
Comparisons made: 0
[1]
Enter input: 3
Comparisons made: 1
[1, 3]
Enter input: 4
Comparisons made: 2
[1, 3, 4]
Enter input: 2
Comparisons made: 3
[1, 2, 3, 4]
Enter input: 5555
Total comparisons: 6
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: The number of comparisons doesn't match with that in the expected output, what can I do about that?

Comment: The number of comparisons is `count += len(new_list)` because you can't break

Comment: @yowhatsup123. I updated my answer. Can you check it please?

Comment: `name 'count' is assigned to before global declaration` this is the error it throws up now

Comment: Sorry my bad, I'm tired... You don't need global... :(

Comment: I ran the code, can you check this once please - https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJJPg.png This particular case had the number 99999 instead of 5555 but I was asked to modify it